# Google Analytics reports 10 times lesser sessions than hits in server logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, apache, google-analytics

Let's say I've a page `mysite.com/mypage`

Landing Page Report in GA for this URL for a specified duration, gives me a number of sessions - say 50.

For the same duration, I checked Apache's access.log, and did a `grep "GET /mypage`, and I've got around 10x more hits -- say 500.

How can we have a 10x anomaly between GA & Server Logs? Where did the hits go?

This anomaly is present for other durations too. I've compared various durations.

Before someone tells the standard reasons for this, let me point out that:

1. A difference of 2x or 3x is understandable, but not 10x.
2. No, this is not Bot Traffic. I extracted all *unique* IPs from the logs, and the IPs are 99% unique. So the traffic is all coming from different IPs.
3. I also analyzed user agents, and they all look real (with various models of phones like iPhone, Samsung etc.)
4. GA also says that this report is based on 100% data (sampling ruled out).
5. As I pointed out, I'm only counting the GET requests to the `/mypage`. That is, I'm not counting asset downloads, favicon hits etc. etc.

I performed another test. I took all IPs, then made them unique, then for each IP I analyzed how many hits came from that IP. I found from 84% of the IPs, there's no second request. They made only 1 request.

I've read [Anamoly between google analytics and server hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979824/anamoly-between-google-analytics-and-server-hits) and have taken care of everything given in the accepted answer.

What could it be? Any clues on how to debug this? The traffic is coming from Paid Facebook Ads.

Comment: If I remember right, Google Analytics adds Javascript that runs in the clients browser.  So if the browser refuses to run it (for whatever reason), the stats will not get to Google.  Your server on the other hand has full control on it's data.

Comment: Facebook has some weird pre-load mechanism on mobile, that fetches data for a lot of external objects just in case the user might want to actually view them ... could play a role in this as well, I suppose. (Though the user agent should contain something specific in such case, some FB... indicating it is their preloader mechanism at work.)

Comment: @CBroe Anything more on that? That may be very likely. I forgot to mention that almost all user-agent strings contain signs that it is the FB in-app browser.

Comment: @Nic3500 True, but for the demographics we run ads in, it is highly unlikely that 9 out of 10 users don't run JS! That's generally not true for the web either

Comment: Apparently that thing is called “Facebook Liger”, check if what is described here matches the requests you’re seeing: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/magento-website-hammering-facebook-liger/

Comment: @CBroe You are spot on! Please just add an answer, so I can accept it! Thanks.. based on your hint, I checked the X-Purpose header, and indeed, FB was sending preview hits 9 out of 10!

Comment: @KazimZaidi cool, glad it helped. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has some sort of pre-load mechanism on mobile, that fetches data for a lot of external objects just in case the user might want to actually view them.

Apparently that thing is called “Facebook Liger”, check if what is described here matches the requests you’re seeing: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/magento-website-hammering-facebook-liger/

You should be able to detect this via the User-Agent header, and maybe exclude those requests from your analytics.

Comment: This was it. We debugged the logs for the special `X-Purpose` header sent by FB, and if the value of this header is `preview`, it means the hit is only a pre-fetch, since FB anticipates a click from the user. 9 out of 10 requests were these `preview` ones, and these request come from user's own IP.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing sessions to pageviews, which is not an apples-to-apples comparison.

A **session** indicates a period of continuous hits (e.g. pageviews, events) before 30 minutes of inactivity. Therefore 1 session could consist of **many** pageviews.

When you are doing a search for `GET /mypage` in your logs, you are looking at how many times that page was requested from your servers. This is equivalent to the **pageview** metric in Google Analytics.

I recommend you compare `pageviews` for `/mypage` against `GET /mypage` entries in your logs. This should give you a much closer comparison.

Keep in mind that it will be rare to get a 100% match due to scenarios where the Google Analytics tag may not fire on the user's browser. Examples of scenarios include:

- GA code doesn't load before user navigates away from the page
- Ad blockers may prevent the tag from firing
- Do not track settings may prevent the tag from firing

Comment: I unique the IPs, so I think its fair to compare that with sessions. Secondly, what you're saying is true, but cannot account for 10x.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the GA JS isn't loading for those "extra" sessions.  If it were loading correctly, there would be one tracking hit sent for each /mypage hit.

The best way to get information on what's happening is to store a local copy of the tracking data sent to Google.  When the GA JS loads correctly, there will be one tracking request sent to Google and another tracking request sent to your web server's log file.

Here's an article that explains how to configure your GA JS code to keep a copy of all tracking requests sent to Google, with syntax examples:

http://support.angelfishstats.com/entries/42575637-How-To-Process-Google-Analytics-Data-with-Angelfish

Once you have the requests, you will see a __ua.gif hit for each request sent to Google.  If you see a hit to /mypage with a FB referral WITHOUT a corresponding __ua.gif hit, you'll want to investigate the details of the /mypage hit.  For example:

- What network & country is associated to the IP address that request /mypage?
- If you examine multiple IP addresses, does a pattern emerge?
- Does the user agent look legit?
- Are the clients using a browser or an app?
- Is FB charging you for the click?

If the hits look bogus, use your findings to complain to FB and get some money back.