# Thousands facebook ip visits a day trigger js error (TypeError: Illegal invocation)

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook

Since May 12th our website gets more than 2000 visits a day that always trigger a js error (in our case `TypeError: Illegal invocation`) with the following characteristics:

- referrer is http://m.facebook.com
- all ips are registered to facebook
- user agent is an iPhone 99.9% of the time, reported screen size is 2000x2000

We'd like to resolve this error but we are not able to find the reason of these sudden visits. If it's a facebook bot or crawler it's not using the correct user agent, on the other hand if it's real users we don't understand why the visits trigger a js error and point to ips registered to facebook.

Unfortunately I didn't get an answer at https://developers.facebook.com

If anyone can help with that would be appreciated

Example ips:

> 31.13.114.53, 173.252.124.54, 173.252.84.115, 66.220.151.89, 173.252.84.86, 66.220.151.178, 66.220.151.90, 31.13.114.117, 173.252.92.114, 173.252.99.252, 69.171.240.18, 173.252.84.92, 69.171.224.213, 69.171.240.252, 69.171.240.23, 173.252.98.119, 173.252.90.170, 66.220.151.180, 66.220.156.22, 31.13.113.198, 173.252.84.88, 173.252.92.113, 173.252.124.57, 69.171.240.16, 69.171.240.17, 173.252.91.252, 31.13.114.50, 31.13.114.48, 66.220.156.23, 173.252.84.89, 173.252.99.17, 173.252.84.55, 31.13.113.192, 69.171.240.22, 66.220.156.60, 173.252.122.60, 66.220.156.18, 31.13.114.114, 31.13.114.119, 173.252.84.56, 173.252.122.54, 69.171.240.20, 173.252.123.183, 173.252.99.246, 173.252.92.244, 173.252.98.28, 31.13.113.195, 66.220.151.93, 66.220.156.16, 66.220.156.19, 66.220.156.17, 173.252.88.118, 173.252.127.23, 69.171.251.10, 173.252.121.118, 31.13.114.116, 31.13.114.146, 173.252.98.114, 173.252.98.117, 66.220.156.20, 173.252.98.27, 31.13.114.6, 31.13.113.197, 173.252.122.57, 69.171.240.21, 173.252.98.112, 173.252.123.182, 173.252.99.20, 173.252.92.116, 66.220.156.55, 66.220.156.150, 173.252.123.181, 31.13.114.51, 173.252.93.19, 173.252.91.251, 31.13.114.49, 173.252.98.86, 173.252.91.247, 173.252.84.91, 173.252.92.117, 173.252.84.116, 66.220.151.86, 66.220.148.169, 69.171.224.249, 31.13.113.194, 173.252.85.26, 66.220.156.145, 31.13.113.180, 31.13.111.90, 173.252.91.248, 173.252.91.250, 69.171.240.247, 173.252.92.241, 173.252.92.118, 173.252.99.23, 173.252.124.120, 173.252.122.59, 173.252.98.26, 173.252.99.52, 66.220.156.146, 31.13.114.12, 66.220.148.170, 173.252.93.18, 173.252.92.208, 31.13.113.176, 69.171.224.210, 69.171.224.211, 173.252.84.113, 31.13.111.84, 31.13.114.52, 69.171.240.248, 173.252.99.189, 173.252.99.183, 31.13.114.208, 69.171.240.251, 69.171.240.253, 173.252.92.115, 31.13.114.112, 173.252.122.58, 173.252.85.27, 173.252.98.80, 173.252.124.122, 173.252.98.25, 173.252.84.87, 66.220.151.208, 31.13.114.145, 173.252.98.85, 173.252.98.84, 69.171.224.214, 69.171.224.209, 173.252.85.25, 66.220.156.56, 66.220.151.181, 173.252.85.49, 173.252.85.48, 66.220.151.211, 173.252.124.60, 173.252.123.185, 69.171.224.215, 173.252.92.240, 31.13.113.196, 173.252.98.115, 66.220.151.241, 173.252.98.82, 31.13.113.193, 66.220.156.149, 173.252.123.184, 173.252.89.22, 173.252.98.29, 173.252.124.119, 69.171.240.19, 173.252.92.247, 66.220.148.171, 66.220.148.166, 69.171.224.247, 173.252.98.113, 173.252.124.124, 173.252.92.246, 173.252.124.61

Comment: _“If it's a facebook bot or crawler it's not using the correct user agent”_ - well which one _is_ it using? That would likely be of more interest than a list of IP addresses … You might be dealing with “Liger”, their preloader for mobile, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326692/1427878

Comment: @CBroe thank you I didn't know about "Linger" yet, as stated above 99% of the time user agent is an iPhone here an example of the last ones

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.1; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; Microsoft; Virtual) like Gecko`